# Wubi is taking a long time to install

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I decided to try the new Ubuntu with Wubi, however I've been installing for 2 hours now and the progress is always around 3 hrs. 30 min. Sometimes it goes to 3 hrs. 28 min., then bounces back to 3 hrs. 40 min. It has been like that for the past 2 hours and I read that the installation should only take less than one hour.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Athlon II X2 4400e
- RAM: 2GB DDR3
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Answer (score 1):

You're installing Ubuntu the day after a release, and you've probably checked the boxes to update from the internet, so the installer is downloading updates and language packs.

The main repositories get *hammered* the day of a release and the following days. The reason your timer is going up and down is because your download speed is varying, and the reason it's taking ages is because the repository is overloaded.

Either start again and don't check the boxes to update components from the internet, or tough it out and wait for it to finish.

If you start again, you can change your software source to a less crowded one using the "Software Sources" tool after installation, and get your updates in the usual manner. There's a wizard that will pick a good repository for you in that tool, or if your ISP offers a mirror (e.g. http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com ) that's probably the best choice.

Comment: I didn't check anything. The wubi installer I just clicked 18GB, my C drive, language, desktop environment, set my pass and then I clicked install..